# Traduction du mot grec "klausígelôs"

Tags: vocabulaire, locutions, grec

Le mot grec *[klausígelôs](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%85%CF%83%CE%AF%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%BB%CF%89%CF%82)* signifie

> rire mêlé de larmes, pleurer de joie, pleurer et rire en même temps

Des descriptions plus littéraires (en anglais) sont données [ici](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YxVpDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=klausigelos&source=bl&ots=3_OIkzwpvW&sig=ACfU3U3n68vFPPeV4fZZekvChj_Kq0ORSQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYxKGoyMjgAhVIOBoKHfy2DZoQ6AEwDnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=klausigelos&f=false) et [ici](http://siti.org/content/meditation-dionysus-smile).

Y a-t-il un mot ou bien une locution en français qui désigne un sentiment voisin ?
En anglais j'ai trouvé *mirth-in-tears*.

Comment: Les larmes ne sont pas toutes de douleurs immédiates, il en est de soulagement qui libère des d’éclats de rire après une tension extrême ou lorsque des blessures anciennes qui ressurgissent violemment arrivent enfin à se libérer aux travers d’émotions instables et intenses…  La crise de la larmes se termine en fou rire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je crois que l'on ne fera pas mieux que le traducteur DeepL qui donne trois options ;

> rires en larmes
>   hilarité dans les larmes
>   rires dans les oreilles

Ce concept n'existe pas en français, ni véritablement en anglais ; il n'est pas dans les dictionnaires ; le terme « mirth-in-tears » provient possiblement d'un besoin de traduction.

Il existe cependant un concept voisin mais qu'il ne faudra pas confondre ; c'est « **rire aux larmes** ». Lorsqu'on dit cela d'une personne on dit tout d'abord que la personne est secouée par une forte crise de rire, un rire incontrôlable qui amène les larmes ; il est donc essentiellement question de rire sain.

> (TLFi) En partic. Rire à en provoquer l'écoulement des larmes.

- Je me chargerais volontiers de faire rire le tribunal avec ça, **de le faire rire aux larmes**, mais je ne me charge pas du tout d'obtenir une séparation, il faudrait autre chose .
- Le colosse, **en riant aux larmes**, m'emporta dans ses bras, me déposa au creux d'un immense lit de campagne tout mou, tout chaud, où je m'endormis aussitôt.

Il existe un autre concept qui implique le rire non pas exactement mêlé au larmes comme si les deux sentiments coexistaient, mais le passage d'un état à l'autre ; cela relève  très probablement d'une maladie mentale, comme on trouve ce comportement chez certains malades mentaux. Néanmoins il est reconnu, tout au moins en une forme qui n'est pas identifiée comme grave, en tant que comportement possible ; ce n'est pas reconnu comme très sain cependant. Il ne faudra donc pas confondre cela avec «  klausígelôs ». La locution pour exprimer ce concept est « **passer du rire aux larmes** ».

> (TlFi) En partic. Passer du rire aux larmes. Manifester une instabilité morale, affective propre aux états d'anxiété, de nervosité.

- Depuis quelques semaines, il lui semblait qu'une transformation s'opérait en Renée; elle paraissait inquiète; elle passait brusquement du rire aux larmes; il la surprenait parfois qui attachait sur lui un regard anxieux.

Je crois comprendre que la joie est une composante du «  klausígelôs » et donc le mot « rire » est à éviter; plus près du modèle anglais (mirth), le mot « hilarité » pourrait passer and on pourrait parler d'« **hilarité dans les larmes** » sans empiéter sur les autres concepts. Cependant l'hilarité est conçue comme causant des explosion de rire et je ne crois que le  «  klausígelôs » soit conçu sur la base de ce rire-là ; c'est plutôt un rire réservé, doux.

Il existe un autre comportement reconnu, qui est identifié par la locution « **pleurer de joie** » ; ce concept rend peut être la notion d'une façon plus précise ; cependant, si selon cette nouvelle possibilité le rire fort n'est plus une composante, la joie, elle, le remplace comme composante principale et le léger rire peut être entièrement inexistant, sa seule manifestation n'étant alors qu'un sourire ; peut être que cela ne reflète pas le mélange de rire et de larmes dans le «  klausígelôs », comme ce serait un mélange à parts égales.

En fin de compte on pourrait parler, donc, d'accès d'hilarité en larmes.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne vois pas d'expression concise et acceptable rendant la dualité présente en grec.

Je suggérerais donc les oxymores :

> S'esclaffer de pleurs
>
> Pleurer aux éclats
>
> Rire à chaudes larmes

Seul le dernier se prête facilement à une substantivisation.

D'un point de vue plus médical, on trouve aussi:

> le rire prodromique (pathologique) mais pas forcément associé à des pleurs
>
> les accès d'émotion bipolaires

Comment: Pas très convaincu… pour avoir été témoin de scènes de ce genre en service de soins palliatifs, je pencherais plutôt pour *une hystérie qui saute des larmes aux rires* rien de littéraire qui satisfasse le traducteur.